# Как найти сумму значений для каждой строки каждого объекта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть список некоторых значений. Мне нужно дополнить этот список разностью значения с предыдущим, а также и суммой этих разностей. При этом, для разных названий сумму нужно обнулять.

Т.к. не могу особо понятно сформулировать, в комментариях к списку написал, чем нужно дополнить каждое значение:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['10:00', 'a', 110],  # += [0,  0]
    ['11:00', 'a', 130],  # += [20, 20]
    ['12:00', 'a', 145],  # += [15, 35]
    ['13:00', 'a', 165],  # += [20, 55]

    ['10:00', 'b', 110],  # += [0,   0]
    ['11:00', 'b', 230],  # += [120, 120]
    ['12:00', 'b', 345],  # += [115, 235]
    ['13:00', 'b', 465],  # += [120, 355]

    ['10:00', 'c', 10],  # += [0,  0]
    ['11:00', 'c', 20],  # += [10, 10]
    ['12:00', 'c', 30],  # += [10, 20]
    ['13:00', 'c', 35],  # += [5,  25]

    ['10:00', 'd', 1],  # += [0, 0]
    ['11:00', 'd', 2],  # += [1, 1]
    ['12:00', 'd', 3],  # += [1, 2]
    ['13:00', 'd', 4],  # += [1, 3]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time', 'name', 'value'])
df.loc[df.name != df.name.shift(), 'diff_value'] = 0
df.loc[df.name == df.name.shift(), 'diff_value'] = df.value.diff()

print(df)
```

Дополнить разностью несложно, но как найти сумму этих разностей?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df["new"] = df.groupby("name")["diff_value"].cumsum()
```

результат:

```
In [131]: df
Out[131]:
     time name  value  diff_value    new
0   10:00    a    110         0.0    0.0
1   11:00    a    130        20.0   20.0
2   12:00    a    145        15.0   35.0
3   13:00    a    165        20.0   55.0
4   10:00    b    110         0.0    0.0
5   11:00    b    230       120.0  120.0
6   12:00    b    345       115.0  235.0
7   13:00    b    465       120.0  355.0
8   10:00    c     10         0.0    0.0
9   11:00    c     20        10.0   10.0
10  12:00    c     30        10.0   20.0
11  13:00    c     35         5.0   25.0
12  10:00    d      1         0.0    0.0
13  11:00    d      2         1.0    1.0
14  12:00    d      3         1.0    2.0
15  13:00    d      4         1.0    3.0
```